# Changing button look n feel after it is selected

Tags: jquery, css, button, jquery-mobile

I am currently using jquery mobile's jcarousel component. I have two jcarousel components. In that, when an item is clicked from the second list, the page refreshes and displays appropriate data. The user has to select an item from first item list and move ahead to second list. I want to highlight the selected button in the first item list. I would need to load the CSS when it is clicked or selected. How should I do it? Also, the css should be applied to only one button. If deselected, the css should unload and the original CSS look and feel should be displayed. It is kinda complex. But can someone provide me an idea here as how to approach this? Let me know if you need any more information. Thank you in anticipation.

Regards,
BG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be a too long winded way to approach this problem but I used it too highlight selected images in jCarousel. I used a library called knockout ( http://knockoutjs.com/ ) and had a data-bind so that when you clicked an image it removed all references to the css class involved on the carousel then added the styling to that new selected picture in the carousel, a red border iirc =D I think if this is the only functionality you want then there is I am sure a better way to go about it but if you need other dynamic functionality, integrating knockout alongside your jcarousel gives you a lot of options.

Upon writing all that I think that the above is a terrible idea for you :D

Instead take a look at using the itemVisibleInCallback and itemVisibleOutCallback. You can have 2 methods for adding and removing the css on the element in your carousel via its list index. Take a look at this link for better information: http://mheidzir.wordpress.com/2009/06/25/how-to-highlight-external-controller-for-jcarousel/

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks Hazza :) I will try to see the links and let you know if anything works out or if I get an easier way :)